# Update Beta App website shows error

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When I try to update the Stack Exchange Beta app, it came up with this message instead of the update screen. This is not random, I have been trying to update for 5-6 times but it's unsuccessful.

[image: !]

Using the HTTP Status Code Checker, I get 400.

Version: 1.3.210

Comment: Whoops, I forgot the tag again... Sorry.

Comment: No worry I got the tag covered. Just a quick question, how many times you tried 'update'?

Comment: Like, clicking the button?

Comment: 4 times at least.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't a one time 'update' request and got some network time out kinda issues.

Comment: Since I'm unable to download the beta version (invite only) I can't see the actual URL. My answer is based on the couple of URL's I found for SE's iOS app. But since you have the beta app URL you can check its status using [HTTP Status Code Checker](http://httpstatus.io/) online tool. Please DO NOT share the actual URL. If your findings are different than what I said in my answer then please submit your answer.

Comment: Status code is 400.

Comment: Thank you for checking and confirming. At least we know HTTP Status code has a mis-match.

Comment: :D no problem. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed. The beta channel directly gets the app from our build server, and whenever our build server is restarted it loses context of the previous build's artifacts, so we had to build a new version. This sadly results in a version number upgrade and a needless update alert on all installed versions, but it's better than having the download link error out.

Answer (score 0):

As per OP's shared screenshot in the post the error code given is **500** i.e. internal error.

I can't update my iOS SE app to beta version of 1.3.210 as it's an invite only. But, I did little research and found out that couple of URLs (*not* shared here and I believe it is a iOS beta download page location) that  shows me the following stats:

On one of the URL Dev. tools 'Network' log shows: (emphasis mine)

> Remote Address:192.111.0.16:443
>
> Request URL:https://mobile.stackexchange.com/* (full URL is hidden)
>
> Request Method:GET
>
> Status Code:**400 Bad Request**

As per [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1): (emphasis mine)

> 10.4.1 **400 Bad Request**
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to **malformed
>   syntax**. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

On the other URLs, I used [HTTP Status Code Checker](http://httpstatus.io/) online tool and it shows:

> [image]
>   [image]

I don't know why the status code are mis-match i.e. 400 HTTP status vs. 500 from Response Body. Hope this will help some way in debugging the issue.

Comment: How is this helpful? The url is a little different, probably relaying to another service which does give the 500 here too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks. I fixed the URL. Please see my updated answer. I always opt for HTTPS mode...

Comment: It *is* in https mode.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I do see the lock icon and that is the reason I had https link but I thought you were pointing at without https. So what do u mean by " url is a little different,"

Comment: I can't share the url, but it is not exact what you see in the screen shot.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I will install an iOS app update and see where it points to.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I can't update to beta ... I don;t see the link. I would appreciate if you could guide me where to get the beta 1.3.210 ver. then I am sure I will be able to correct my answer and these downvote reverse.

Comment: You can't. You have to be invited.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Please see my updated answer. Hope this will help and may help me to get downvote reverse.

Comment: HTTP 400 != 500 as in the question. A HTTP 500 can only be diagnosed server side.

Comment: @PatrickHofman True. and my analysis is based on the couple of URL's found for SE's iOS app.  Anyway, since you have the beta app URL you can see its [HTTP Status Code Checker](http://httpstatus.io/) - For me both came to 400 Bad Request.

Comment: So the proxy returned HTTP 400 while the actual server returned HTTP 500. So how does that help?

Comment: @PatrickHofman See my updated answer and that's all I can debug here.

Comment: Well. The nature of a HTTP 500 makes it almost impossible to diagnose this from our side.

Comment: You are sometimes wasting your time on things you really can't solve. This one here is clearly a bug that only a developer working on the actual code can fix.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understand. We don't always solve issues 100% but if we can debug and post our findings that may help in certain way.

Comment: But this one here doesn't really help. Don't misunderstand me, I think you're doing great job, but just a friendly advice is to spend the time on things you can help better, e.g. that latest answer on the test tools of SE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks. No no, I understand your point. But, even official answer says "it's better than having the download link error" and I was after the download link's HTTP Status Code which I could not able to get as beta download link is 'invite only' but OP had it and he confirmed the link error with status code match. Anyway, why would download link return two different 'status codes'. So I thought of posting the same.